# Extension of Slutsky's Theorem

Tags: probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I regard random variables $X_n$ and $Y_n$ with $(X_n+Y_n) \rightarrow (X+Y)$ (in distribution for $n \to \infty$). Furthermore there exist random variables $(a_n) \rightarrow 1$ and $(b_n) \rightarrow 1$ (both in distribution for $n \to \infty$).
Does also $(a_nX_n+b_nY_n) \rightarrow (X+Y)$ hold in distribution?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky's_theorem I believe so since you apply 2nd property twice, followed by the first property.

Answer (score 0):

It is true if the sequences $(X_n)_n$ and $(Y_n)_n$ are such that for all sequence of random variables $(\delta_n)$ converging to $0$ in probability, the sequences  $(\delta_nX_n)_n$ and $(\delta_nY_n)_n$ goes to zero in probability. This holds for example if $\lim_{R\to \infty}\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\Pr\{ \left\lvert X_n\right\rvert\gt R\}=0$ (indeed, 
$$
\Pr\{\left\lvert  \delta_nX_n  \right\rvert\gt\varepsilon\}\leqslant 
\Pr\{\left\lvert  X_n  \right\rvert\gt R\}+\Pr\{\left\lvert  \delta_n  \right\rvert\gt\varepsilon/R\},
$$
take the $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$ and exploit the fact that $R$ is arbitrary
).

In this case, write 
$$
a_nX_n+b_nY_n=X_n+Y_n+\left(a_n-1\right)X_n+\left(b_n-1\right)Y_n=:X_n+Y_n+R_n,
$$
where $R_n\to 0$ in probability.

Without this assumption on $X_n$ and $Y_n$, this may fail: the choice $X_n=n$, $Y_n=-n$, $a_n=1$ and $b_n=1-(\ln n)^{-1}$ gives a counter-example.